# access to checkboxes within Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I have a problem regarding the access to check boxes within Matlab uitable.I have a table in Matlab GUI that has a column of check boxes. I want to open a particular pdf file when a check box is clicked.
But I can't find callback of the check boxes within the uitable.
Hope the problem is statement is clear.

thanks in advance,
Abhirup

Answer (score 1):

Create your own [`CellEditcallback`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable-properties.html) for your table.

Take the following example:

```
function testcode
% Initialize a basic GUI
h.myfig = figure;

% Initialize a dummy table
cnames = {'a','b'};
cformat = {'char', 'logical'};
rnames = {'1','2'};
mydata = {'firstfile', false; 'secondfile', false};
h.mytable = uitable( ...
    'Parent', h.myfig, ...
    'CellEditCallback', @boxchecked, ...
    'ColumnFormat', cformat, ...
    'ColumnName', cnames, ...
    'ColumnEdit', true, ...
    'RowName', rnames, ...
    'Data', mydata ...
    );

guidata(h.myfig,h); % Store handles for later
end

function boxchecked(hObject,eventdata)
h = guidata(hObject); % Retrieve handles
% Your code here
end
```

Set a [breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) in the `boxchecked` function and look at the data given to you by `eventdata` (see also the [general callback documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html)). Three important fields are the `Indices` field, which gives you the cell that was edited and caused the callback to execute, and the `PreviousData` and `NewData` fields, which give you the before and after values of the edited cell.

You'll also want to check to see whether or not the edited cell is a checkbox (`CellEditCallback` executes on any change to a cell in a table). Based on this data, decide what action(s) you want to take.